# Why $|g| \leq \|g\|_{\infty}$? Help with the notion of essential supp

Tags: measure-theory, support-function

I got stuck in the definition of the essential support of $f$. I basically want to prove [Hölder's inequality](http://https:/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) for the case $p=1$ and $q= \infty$. The proof is based on the fact that
$$|g| \leq \|g\|_{\infty} \;\;\text{a.e.}$$
Now I don't see why this should be true by the definition of the essential support of $g$. This is given as follow:
$$\|g\|_{\infty}:=\sup\{t >0 \,|\, \mu\{x \in E:|f(x)|>t\}>0\}$$
But why we have than the inequality $|g| \leq \|g\|_{\infty}$?

Many thanks for some help!

Comment: $|g|\leq \|g\|_\infty$ a.e.

Comment: $\operatorname{ess sup} f$ is also equal to $\inf\{t\in\Bbb R\,:\, f(x)\le t\text{ almost everywhere}\}$, which is also a minimum.

Comment: Ofc. a.e. but I don't see it still, could you please give some more details? @GeorgeBrown

Comment: @FrederickManfred See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed,
$$\|f\|_\infty = \inf \{C \geq 0: |f(x) |\leq C \  \text{ for a.e. $x\in \Omega$}\}.\tag{$\star$}$$
You can easily prove that $\|f\|_\infty$ defined in eq. ($\star$) is equal to yours.

There exists a sequence $C_n\geq 0$ such that $C_n \to \|f\|_\infty$ and for each $n$, $|f(x)|\leq C_n$ a.e. on $\Omega$.
Therefore $|f(x)|\leq C_n$ for all $x\in \Omega\setminus E_n$, with $\mu(E_n) =0$. We set $E= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, so that
$\mu(E)= 0$ and
$$|f(x)|\leq C_n\ \ \ \forall n, \quad \forall x\in \Omega \setminus E;$$
it follows that $|f(x)|\leq \|f\|_\infty$, $\forall x\in \Omega\setminus E$.